# Laravel 5.6, MySQL 5.7, Cannot select the new JSON type field

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I am storing some data inside `mysql` using the `JSON` Type field.
When I try to select query my json data field in Laravel 5.6, I get an exception

```
 $transactions = DB::table('transactions')
       ->select('transactions.uuids_json', '... other columns')
....

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2036, query exception
```

If I remove the `uuids_json` field, everything works normal. Do I have to somehow use raw statements or something?

The column `uuid_json` data field contains rows like this:

```
["1a7b29b8-5009-4266-8192-508930f2f92a", "3d52cfd5-d3c0-467f-8da1-cf81c344ad20", "cbe6e7fb-d806-49e2-8616-3c28afa012fe", "dfda9df5-2cbf-4cb8-aa54-a6dc23f73995"]
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/json-column-problem-with-mysql57-and-laravel52 have claimed success by removing the php-mysql and (re)installing php-mysqlnd also make sure you have the latest minor revision of PHP 5.6 which currently is 5.6.35

Comment: I will try this, I am using PHP 7.1.14, but can switch down to 5.6

Comment: My bad I thought the 5.6 was for PHP but it was for laravel. 7.1 should be fine

Answer (score 3):

This sounds related to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70384

Make sure your PHP install is using the **mysqlnd** 5.0.11 or later, which according to that bug log should include the fix.

Check `php -i` or `phpinfo()` for the version of mysqlnd you use.

If you can't upgrade to a version of the library that supports the JSON data type, a workaround is to CAST the JSON column to a string:

```
->select(\DB::raw("CAST(transactions.uuids_json as CHAR) as uuids_json"), ...)
```

Comment: Hi, I am using `mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev`, I will try the cast statement.

Comment: Maybe the claim that 5.0.11 fixed the issue was premature.