# Eloquent function works on localhost but breaks on linux web server

Tags: php, laravel

This short eloquent firstOrCreate function is not working on linux web server. I've tried in localhost on windows and its working fine but as you can see the exception below, query string is not encoded properly.

Running on Laravel 5.8
PHP 7.3 with MySQL 5.7

```
$search = SearchHistory::firstOrCreate([
                    'ip_address'    => request()->ip(),
                    'data'          => json_encode(request()->query())
                ], [
                    'user_id'       => auth()->id() ?? 0,
                    'user_agent'    => request()->userAgent()
                ]);
```

The formatted query should be like:

```
select * from `search_histories` where (`ip_address` = '127.0.0.1' and `data` = '{\"inc_surrounding\":\"on\",\"address\":\"Surry Hills, New South Wales, Australia\"}') limit 1
```

But i'm getting this error..

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY000)
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2036 (SQL: select * from `search_histories` where (`ip_address` = 27.34.72.242 and `data` = {"address":"Surry Hills, New South Wales, Australia","radius":"10","price":{"min":"100000","max":"800000"},"bedroom":"0","bathroom":"0","parking":"0","land_size":{"min":null,"max":null}}) limit 1)
```

Comment: You can usually ignore the encoding in these error messages. They are inserted via PDO, so as long as you're using the correct methods, it's correct. Have you run all of your migrations?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864391/laravel-5-2-query-building-for-json-on-columns and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846442/laravel-5-6-mysql-5-7-cannot-select-the-new-json-type-field

Comment: Yes, all my migrations are up to date..

Comment: Okay, I got it solved, thanks.